# swift 5 generic model variable name changing

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I have a model:

```
struct PickList: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

And this model can contain variable with another `PickList` model. And it variable name can change. Like:

```
struct PickList: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let anotherModel: PickList
}
// or 
struct PickList: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let someModel: PickList
}
```

And have swift some logic for it like:

```
struct PickList<T: String>: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let T: PickList?
}
```

this is not work :)

Comment: No, this isn't a valid Swift. Generics are placeholders for **types** (like `String`, or `Int`, or `Foo`), not for identifiers. What do you actually want to achieve, because it seems like you're asking about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can do that with a fixed struct member name and a custom `keyDecodingStrategy`.

Comment: Structs can't hold variables of the same type. You could use a class instead. But you have to implement the decoder and encoder methods your self in that case.